# Showing White blank screen after deployed in github (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, hosting, package-lock.json

Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Package-lock.json :

```
  "name": "tic_tac_toe", 
  "version": "0.1.0",   
  "homepage": "https://richardshaju.github.io/tictactoe",     
  "lockfileVersion": 3,   "requires": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"homepage": "https://richardshaju.github.io/tictactoe"
```

This line should only include in package.json